# How to convert the link of resized image to byte array

Tags: javascript, angular, image, file, asynchronous

#newbie question -
The result of resizing an image is a url that can be set to the html element `src` - how can I get its byte array (the data) in order to send it to the server for storing in DB?

my code for resizing the image

```
private imgThumbnail(file){
            
    if(file && file.type && file.type.includes("image")){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
            imgElement.src = e.target.result as string;             
            
            imgElement.onload = (e) =>{
                const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = 100;
                canvas.height = 100;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(e.target as HTMLImageElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                 
                const srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                return srcEncoded;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

- Also what is the correct syntax for receiving `this.imgThumbnail` result?  this didn't work `this.imgThumbnail(files[0]) = imageUrl => { console.log('imageUrl = ' + imageUrl );}`

it returned an error

```
Module parse failed: Assigning to rvalue (427:8)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         }
>         this.imgThumbnail(files[0]) = imageUrl  => {
|             console.log('imageUrl = ' + imageUrl );
|         };
```

Comment: Are you showing the re-sized image or just wanted to resize it before sending to the backend?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara the resize works fine, I just want to receive the returned value `srcEncoded` in the calling function and send its bytes to server without displaying it

Comment: Why don't you use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-compress) ?